# Clear history webbrowser in window phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my application, i use webbrowser control.

```
#region show adve....
        public void ShowAd(string link)
        {
            linkFromservices = "http://ads.diadiem.com/www/delivery/afr.php?refresh=10&zoneid=66&...=";
            client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(linkFromservices, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }

        void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            result = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                result = e.Result;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                {
                    result = AddScripttoHTML(result);
                    webBrowser.NavigateToString(result);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
            finally
            {
                result = string.Empty;
                client.DownloadStringCompleted -= new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

in this link "http://ads.diadiem.com/www/delivery/afr.php?refresh=10&zoneid=66&..." you can see refesh=10 . Every 10 seconds the browser will automatically refresh and change the current advertising alone by random.....

but refresh the memory increased from 200KB to 400KB.

how to release or clear History webbrowser in window phone 7 ?

Thank you all ! please help me.......

Comment: To be clear, does the memory increase by 200K-400K every time the ad is refreshed? It doesn't look like an issue with web browser history, but it would appear you are using more memory in your app with each refresh.

Comment: hi Paul Annetts, webbrowser auto reset every time. Web site use Java Script to refesh it.

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is - is it the memory increase? The browser history?

Answer (score 0):

The webbrowser controle for WP7 is unable to clear history, you need to create your own webbrowser :

http://franciscojf.wordpress.com/2011/03/27/full-web-browser-control-for-windows-phone-7/