# Clearing CacheMemory of WebBrowser

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to clear the Cache of a `WebBrowser` control dynamically in Windows Phone 7.1 using C#. Previously selected images are loading again in my `WebBrowser`, has anyone ran into this before?

Answer (score 3):

Clearing Cache in WP7.1 is not possible.
The workaround can be to force the browser to load fresh page each time. This can be accomplished in many ways such as:
 - Using **False Query** i.e. Passing a random parameter in location of web page  like  */page.html?q=5* 
 - Using **tags** based methods to prevent caching (google it)
 - passing **no-cache** headers from server itself

Answer (score 2):

On Windows Phone 8 you can use the extension method [ClearInternetCacheAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj571213%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

This won't work on WP7.1 however. See [another StackOverflow question that deals with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171409/clear-history-webbrowser-in-window-phone-7).

Comment: Previously selected images are loading again in the webbrowser,is there any other ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For clearing images this code can be helpfull to you.

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = image.Source as BitmapImage;
bitmapImage.UriSource = null;
image.Source = null;
```

This works. happy coding